# Валидация формы загрузки файла yii

Tags: yii

Необходимо оставить поле загрузки файлов необязательным для заполнения.
Правила:

```
array('id_object, id_user, content, pluses, minuses', 'required'),
        ...
array('picture_1, picture_2, picture_3', 'file', 'types'=>'ico, jpg, gif, png','maxSize' => 1048576*2),
```

Почему-то поле все равно является обязательным для заполнения. Работает, если последнюю строку вообще убрать. Но проверка на картинки и размер нужны.

Что не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилось добавлением в последнюю строку:

```
'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
```